# truthiness / boolean comparison in vim

Tags: vimrc

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following equivalence produces two different results:

```
echom a:events == '*' 
echom string(a:events) == '*'
```

The first one returns `1` while the second one returns `0`. Why is this so?

Comment: what is a:events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim, `string()` does *not* mean cast or convert a value to a string.  It means create a new string which can be `eval`'d back the original value:

```
eval(string(x)) ==# x
```

So assuming `a:events` is a sting with the literal value `*`, then `string(a:events)` is the literal value `'*'`.  The string had 1 character, but now has 3 characters.

As another example,

```
echo 'hello'->string()->string()->string()
```

gives

```
'''''''hello'''''''
```

#### Casting strings in vim script

Explicitly casting to a string is not always needed (as opposed to some other languages) since numbers are automatically converted to/from strings when necessary.  For example,

```
strlen(123) = 3
```

Although vim script *does* have a distinct number and string type, you generally don't need to keep track of it yourself.  But if you do need it, there's are a couple of options:

1: Since the only issue with `string()` is when the type is already string, we can just check first.

```
let x = type(x) == v:t_string ? x : string(x)
```

2: Per the documentation %s performs the conversion to string like `:echo`

```
printf('%s', x)
```

Comment: what would be the closest thing to 'cast to string' in vimscript? Or does that not really exist?

Comment: using string() carefully :)  please see my edit.